# SyncAdapter onPerformSync() gets called on emulator but NOT when run on physical device

Tags: android-syncadapter

I have followed [Google's tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html) to use a SyncAdapter with a **dummyAccount** and **no ContentProvider.**

The tutorial is quite straight forward, and I'm aware of the limitations of using stubs for the Account and ContentProvider. I implemented it and when run on the emulator, it works wonderfully. I see the message in the **Log** of when it is periodically called with `periodicSync(..)` and when I request specifically to be called with `requestSync(..)`.

Here is the mind-blowing part, when I run the app on my BQ 5 HD (Android 4.1.2) the SyncAdapter is **never ever** called. If re-installed the app, but nothing seems to be happening. I've wasted weeks with this, and I can´t figure it out.

Here is the my **manifestFile**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    ....Whole bunch of activities...

    <provider
        android:name="com.sf.app_name.stubs.StubProvider"
        android:authorities="com.sf.app_name.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:syncable="true" />

    <service android:name="com.sf.app_name.stubs.AuthenticatorService" 
               android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
            android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="com.sf.app_name.sync.SyncService"
        android:exported="false"
        android:process=":sync" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
            android:resource="@xml/syncadapter" />
    </service>

</application>
```

**authenticator.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <account-authenticator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                       android:accountType="com.sf.app_name"
                       android:userVisible="false" />
```

**syncadapter.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <sync-adapter
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:contentAuthority="com.sf.app_name.provider"
        android:accountType="com.sf.app_name"
        android:userVisible="false"
        android:supportsUploading="false"
        android:allowParallelSyncs="true"
        android:isAlwaysSyncable="true"/>
```

Input is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally figured out what's wrong thanks to ye-old-faithful `Log.d(...)`. It's a definite noob mistake and I'm posting the answer to prevent other beginners from committing the same mistake.

In my code where I create and add the "dummyAccount" needed by the SyncAdapter framework, I did the following:

```
  Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccounts();
    if(accounts.length == 0){
        Account newAccount = new Account(ACCOUNT, ACCOUNT_TYPE);
        ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(newAccount, AUTHORITY, 1);
        ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(newAccount, AUTHORITY, true);  
        ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(newAccount, AUTHORITY, new Bundle(), 40l);
        accountManager.addAccountExplicitly(newAccount, null, null);
        Log.d("serverSync", "ContetResolver set periodic sync");
    }
```

The method`getAccounts()` returns **all of the accounts** associated to the device. **Obviously** it is going to return ZERO when run in the emulator because the emulator has no account associated whatsoever. So I thought it save to do it like this. I create my account of type `ACCOUNT_TYPE` add it, and go merrily along my way. (By the way, the reason for the `addPeriodicSync` on top of the `setIsSyncable` and `setSyncAutomatially` is to solve a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22622364/syncadapter-not-getting-called-on-network-tickle) that pertains to another matter.

Ofcourse, the SyncAdapter of my APP was getting called when the following was executed:

```
ContentResolver.requestSync(signedInAccountInstance.getDummyAccount(),
                               AccountManagerActivity.AUTHORITY, bundle);
```

They `getDummyAccount(..)` was gotten like so:

```
 Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccounts();
 return accounts[0];
```

When this was run on the actual physical device, I should have realized that **getAccounts(..)** would also return (atleast) the gmail account associated to my Android device. Hence when I would do

```
ContentResolver.requestSync(signedInAccountInstance.getDummyAccount(),
                               AccountManagerActivity.AUTHORITY, bundle);
```

the "dummyAccount" sent would be Google's AccountType, and hence why my app's **SyncAdapter** would never be called. Instead, it was the gmail app's SyncAdapter who was getting called with my bundle. 
How did I discover this? By printing out my dummyAccount in Log after looking into the Accounts of my physical device under Settings>Accounts, and realizing that for some reason when I executed my app on my mobile, my gmail account would display a "sync error".

All this could have been prevented by doing things correctly the first time:

```
Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType(ACCOUNT_TYPE);
```

Where `ACCOUNT_TYPE` is static final variable used in my app.

```
    // An account type, in the form of a domain name
public static final String ACCOUNT_TYPE = "com.sf.app_name";
```

Hope this helps save someone some headaches.